# Как спрятать информацию в .env

Tags: python, безопасность, шифрование, .env

У меня есть файл .env, в котором есть ключ от сервисного аккаунта Гугла. Мне нужно перебросить проект на Python на чужой сервер, Windows Server. Как мне сделать так, чтобы сам Python мог юзать ключ, а тот, кто зайдет в .env файл не мог бы его прочитать вообще или добраться до него.

Так как это мс сервер, возможно, если закатать в экзешник до .env файла будет не добраться?

Comment: Ну так пусть Ваш клиент сам сделает ключ

Comment: @ClarkDevlin это мой проект. Просто он будет крутиться на чужом сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как по мне, никак. При желании, человек все равно доберется до исходных данных, ведь у него есть исходники на Python

Но если взять извращения, то должна быть скомпилированная программа, которую мы запускаем. Она берет исходный код Python файла/файлов, добавляет в него соль, например в виде даты и времени и секретного слова, и после генерирует хэш. Также, хэш генерируется и в этой программе и сверяет их или же просто напрямую сверяет исходный код с вшитым в программу

Если все ок, то запускается Python скрипт с переданными в него параметрами в виде важных данных, которые будут в будущем использованы

По идее, нужно хорошо подумать, чтобы обойти подобные извращения

Ну или есть взять попроще вариант, можно просто скомпилировать программу на Python, тем самым скрыв её код. Туда же вшить данные из .env, но существуют простые декомпиляторы py файлов, что с легкостью поможет добраться до сокровенной информации